# C# OpenXml Accept All Revisions in .docx

Tags: c#, openxml, docx, revision

How can I accept all revisions in .docx file using Open XML SDK for .NET? I've tryed to use [this example from Microsoft's Open XML SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/open-xml/how-to-accept-all-revisions-in-a-word-processing-document), but that code does't handling many cases, such as:

- removed row from table is still present in document after accepting revision
- removed item from unordered list is still present in document after accepting revision
- removed empty paragraphs is still present in document after accepting revisions

Is there an easy way to accept all revisions or I should only manually catch and handle all possible cases?

Comment: I suggest to google for Eric White blog posts and videos  on that. I believe he was the one who wrote that document you have linked. Had to work on this in the past, it's a tough one.

Answer (score 3):

Following up on the comment from [Michael Daniloff](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54462425/c-sharp-openxml-accept-all-revisions-in-docx#comment95735706_54462425), Eric White is the current maintainer of the [OpenXmlPowerTools](https://github.com/EricWhiteDev/Open-Xml-PowerTools) project which provides a C# library for accepting the changes (see [this example](https://github.com/EricWhiteDev/Open-Xml-PowerTools/blob/vNext/OpenXmlPowerToolsExamples/RevisionAccepter01/RevisionAccepter01.cs)). Here's a small example of how to use it:

```cs
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging;
using OpenXmlPowerTools;

public static void AcceptRevisions(string file_name) {
    using(WordprocessingDocument doc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(file_name, true))
        RevisionAccepter.AcceptRevisions(doc);
}
```

This handles the additional cases that the original Microsoft example missed (like table formatting changes, etc.).